# Flutter generates error when use the command flutter build windows

Tags: flutter

I create an app using Flutter.

I was able to generate a project for android, ios, and mac platforms.

Now, I copy my entire project to my Windows and try to use the command

```
flutter build windows
```

But I got the following error:

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path =
'G:\Projetos\Pessoal\cryptocoin-historical-price-flutter\crypto_coin_historical\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\msix' (OS Error: Função incorreta.  
, errno = 1)".
A crash report has been written to G:\Projetos\Pessoal\cryptocoin-historical-price-flutter\crypto_coin_historical\flutter_07.log.
```

This is the log that was generated:

Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

flutter build windows

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path = 'G:\Projetos\Pessoal\cryptocoin-historical-price-flutter\crypto_coin_historical\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\msix' (OS Error: Função incorreta.
, errno = 1)

```
#0      _Link.throwIfError (dart:io/link.dart:263:7)
#1      _Link.createSync (dart:io/link.dart:184:5)
#2      ForwardingLink.createSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_link.dart:20:16)
#3      ForwardingLink.createSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_link.dart:20:16)
#4      _createPlatformPluginSymlinks (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_plugins.dart:1029:12)
#5      createPluginSymlinks (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_plugins.dart:964:5)
#6      buildWindows (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:50:3)
#7      BuildWindowsCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_windows.dart:57:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19042.928], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at D:\Programas\flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (12 days ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Programas\AndroidSDK
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: D:\Programas\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32328.378
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at D:\Programas\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19042.928]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.55

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Find out the problem

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter
 msix: ^2.6.5
```

Just need to comment on the line "msix: ^2.6.5"

The problem is fixed.

But now I don't know how to create the msix file that I need to upload to Windows Store.